# Markers not added when orientation change

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a Google map fragment and I am populating it with markers from an URL. I am placing them when the app starts and everything works, but when orientation changes or I switch to another activity and then go back no markers get added even though I can see with Log calls that the method gets called.

My code:

```
        latitudes = new ArrayList<String>();
        longitudes = new ArrayList<String>();

        XMLDataHandler getXML = new XMLDataHandler(); 
        getXML.execute("");

        latitudes = getXML.getLatitudes();
        longitudes = getXML.getLongitudes();
        while(getXML.isDone != true)
        {
            latitudes = getXML.getLatitudes();
            longitudes = getXML.getLongitudes();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < latitudes.size(); i++)
        {
            Double latitude;
            Double longitude;

            String lat;
            String lon;
            if(!latitudes.get(i).equals("") || !longitudes.get(i).equals("") )
            {
                lat = latitudes.get(i).toString();
                lat = lat.replace(",", ".");

                lon = longitudes.get(i);
                lon = lon.replace(",", ".");
                Log.d("LON", "LON: " + lon);

                latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon);

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("");
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            }

        }
```

I hope someone can help me. I am going crazy as to why my markers ain't getting placed when orientation changes.

Comment: Where did you put those code?

Comment: @tinysunlight I put it into my function called "retrieveXML" and the function gets called in OnCreate

Comment: Why did the method gets called when you switch to another activity and then go back if you put it in onCreated?

Comment: I haven't used GoogleMap.But I think you should add GoogleMap.onResume in onResume of your Activity.GoogleMap.onDestroy in onDestroy of your Activity and so on.

Comment: @tinysunlight Thanks for the methods! Seems like it is those I need. I'll try them out!